# mass of the decks in the crewed SpaceX Starship

Tags: spacex, crewed-spaceflight, spacex-starship, mass

I want to work out the approximate mass of a Starship (crewed version) deck. We can assume an internal diameter of 8 meters with a 1.5 meter diameter central support tube. The loading is uncertain but probably variable between 5-10 metric tonnes per deck (on Earth).

Does anyone know how to work out a rough estimate of the mass of the deck? We can assume any well established technology is used to minimise the mass. During launch acceleration of up to 3g may be experienced.

Comment: Might sound snarky, but I'd suggest asking ol' Musky himslef on twitter. You may get a useful response.

Comment: Please clarify the unit **mt**. Is it millitonnes, meter-tonnes, metric tons, or something else?

Comment: @Fred, although I am sure it is not what Slarty wants, "mt" needs no clarification because it is defined inside the SI-System: millitonnes ... quite complicated way to say "Kilogram". (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonne#Symbol_and_abbreviations) ... So the question should be: "Slarty: i think the spaceship can carry more than 10 Kg per deck"

Comment: Very droll metric tonnes. I will update the text thank you.